# Difference between df[,1:3] vs df [,i:i+2] , i=1

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df1`, which is like the below. When I `print(df1[,1:3])`, I get the first 3 columns which is my expectation. But when I use `i=1; print( df1[,i:i+2])` I can only get the 3rd column. Does anybody know the reason?

```
t.x    t.y t.Freq prop.row.x prop.row.y prop.row.Freq prop.col.x
1 Female   None     25     Female       None     0.4237288     Female
2   Male   None     17       Male       None     0.6800000       Male
3 Female   Some     12     Female       Some     0.2033898     Female
4   Male   Some      2       Male       Some     0.0800000       Male
5 Female Marked     22     Female     Marked     0.3728814     Female
6   Male Marked      6       Male     Marked     0.2400000       Male
```

Comment: `:` takes precedence over `+`, so you get `1 + 2`

Comment: Meaning... try `i:(i+2)` instead. or `i + 0:2`

Comment: This is circle 8.1.3: precedence in the [r inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: @Mindy in general, I find that the `seq()` is much saver to use then `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the `2` is being added element-wise to `i:i` (which is `1` for `i = 1`), since `:` has a higher evaluation precedence than `+`.

To be evaluated in the right order, the second argument of the colon operator needs parentheses, i.e.

```
> i = 1L
> i:i + 2L
[1] 3

> i:(i + 2L)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html) has a [related question](http://7.33%20Why%20are%20powers%20of%20negative%20numbers%20wrong?):

> The precedence rules are documented in ?Syntax, and to see how R interprets an expression 
>       you can look at the parse tree

```
R> as.list(quote(-2^2))
[[1]]
`-`

[[2]]
2^2
```

So you can do that with your expression:

```
>  as.list(quote(i:i+2))
[[1]]
`+`

[[2]]
i:i

[[3]]
[1] 2
```

I encourage you to look at `?Syntax` to get a more complete understanding of the precedence of operators in R.